# Is there a difference between nomenclature and iupac

Tags: discussion, tags

The description of [nomenclature](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) gives

> The naming of molecules and elements, usually according to IUPAC standards, but also the accepted uses of traditional ones.

There is currently no description for [iupac](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iupac).

I am therefore wondering if these two can actually be distinguished or are they the same. I would suggest merging and keeping iupac as synonym.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The IUPAC is the [International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iupac) does more than work to standardize the symbols and nomenclature of chemistry, although this is the work they are most famous for. They are also responsible for international efforts to promote chemistry, such as the International Year of Chemistry. Additionally, they disseminate knowledge about chemistry through the publication of various books. The [iupac](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iupac) should be reserved for questions about the IUPAC itself, its operations, organization, members, and activities, and not for questions about [nomenclature](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature). Three of the five questions tagged [iupac](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iupac) are about organic nomenclature (which is where most students encounter the IUPAC for the first time). One is about the names of simple inorganic molecules which do not appear to be systematic (or rather, how to learn to correlate such names with structures). These four questions should be tagged [nomenclature](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) (and only two of them are). The fifth question is about drawing standards, and may be appropriately tagged.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I have not thought about that. So I see that we should keep IUPAC as a tag, like you suggested, but that does not help if we do not have questions related to that tag. The tag would therefore vanish, if we just retag all questions appropriately. I always wanted to know more about this organisation, maybe now is the time to ask some questions.